# Get floodfill outputs (connected pixels) copied into a new mat

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, flood-fill

Is there a convenient way to create a new Mat from the outputs of a `floodfill` operation? I want to get a mat of only the pixels which are detected as connected to the seed pixel and are flood filled technically.

Guess that I executed `floodFill` method to a certain seed point and only 1/4 of the total pixels were filled as they were connected. I want to copy those pixels only to a new image, which represent only those 1/4 number of pixels and most probably smaller than the original input image.

I did this anyway via a very long,higher time+cpu consuming approach. In brief my approach was giving different colors for different `floodfill` calls and keep records of pixels of same color in a separate data structure, and etc.

I want to know if there is a direct and easier approach using the Mask created by `floodfill` or using any other approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you need exactly.
Please take a look at this code, and check if `croppedResult` is what you want.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Create a test image
    Mat1b img(300, 200, uchar(0));
    circle(img, Point(150, 200), 30, Scalar(255));
    rectangle(img, Rect(30, 50, 40, 20), Scalar(255));
    rectangle(img, Rect(100, 80, 30, 40), Scalar(255));

    // Seed inside the circle
    Point seed(160, 220);

    // Setting up a mask with correct dimensions
    Mat1b mask;
    copyMakeBorder(img, mask, 1, 1, 1, 1, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));

    Rect roi;
    uchar seedColor = 200;
    floodFill(img, mask,
        seed + Point(1,1),  // Since the mask is larger than the filled image, a pixel (x,y) in image corresponds to the pixel (x+1,y+1) in the mask
        Scalar(0),          // If FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY is set, the function does not change the image ( newVal is ignored),
        &roi,               // Minimum bounding rectangle of the repainted domain.
        Scalar(5),          // loDiff
        Scalar(5),          // upDiff 
        4 | (int(seedColor) << 8) | FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY);
        // 4-connected | with defined seedColor | use only the mask 

    // B/W image, where white pixels are the one set to seedColor by floodFill
    Mat1b result = (mask == seedColor);

    // Cropped image
    roi += Point(1,1);
    Mat1b croppedResult = result(roi);

    return 0;
}
```

Test image `img`:

[image]

Mask `mask` after `floodFill`:

[image]

Mask `result` with only `seedColor` pixels:

[image]

Cropped mask `croppedResult`:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

```
    // B/W image, where white pixels are the one set to seedColor by floodFill
    Mat1b resultMask = (mask == seedColor);
    Mat1b resultMaskWithoutBorder = resultMask(Rect(1,1,img.cols,img.rows));

    Mat3b originalImage;
    cvtColor(img, originalImage, COLOR_GRAY2BGR); // Probably your original image is already 3 channel

    Mat3b imgMasked(img.size(), Vec3b(0,0,0));
    originalImage.copyTo(imgMasked, resultMaskWithoutBorder);

    Mat3b croppedResult = imgMasked(roi);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do not understand these statements.|||||
    Mat1b result = (mask == seedColor);

    // Cropped image
    roi += Point(1,1);
    Mat1b croppedResult = result(roi);||||
And what is that roi parameter of floodfill and what is stored there?

Comment: Select only pixel with value == seedColor; translate Rect 1 px down and 1 px right; get a submatrix using the Rect. As doc says, roi is the bounding box of the floodfilled points.

Comment: Really interesting..!!! But why should we  translate Rect 1 px down and 1 px right;? Is that because the roi is given related to the original image and? I know the mask is anyway 1 pixel wider and taller than original and is the increasement is from top and left sides?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The mask has is 2 px larger than original image (1 left, 1 right) and 2 px higher (1 up, 1 down)

Comment: And I think as I want finally to get a part of the original image the cropping should be done from original image too. i.e:  Mat1b croppedResult = img(roi); (roi += Point(1,1); call should not be made)

Comment: Yes, you can crop from original image without adding Point(1,1)

Comment: But now occurs another problem. The pixels which are beyond the circle area, but yet inside the bounding rec will also be copied from the original image. I want only the pixels in the circle area.

Comment: Check updated answer. You just need to use `copyTo` with a mask. You should take care of initializing matrices and that dimensions and channels agree.

Comment: Ok, I will get back to you after trying this. I think this will do my job.

Comment: One other thing.|| Mat1b resultMask = (mask == seedColor); What is actually happened here. I mean how the matrix operation is internally done? I am not familiar with this kind of operations. If the explanation is larger a relevant link is appreciated.

Comment: [OpenCV MatExpr](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions): Comparison: A cmpop B, A cmpop alpha, alpha cmpop A, where cmpop is one of :  >, >=, ==, !=, <=, <. The result of comparison is an 8-bit single channel mask whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

Comment: It basically creates a binary mask `resultMask` where pixels whose value is equal to `seedColor` in `mask`are set to 255, or 0 otherwise